# get attribute value of XML child node with where condition on parent node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a `Process` table in sql server database like this:

[image: Proccess Table]

workflowXML column has values like this:

```
<Tasks>  
  <Task type="start" id="Task_038517r">
    <TaskUsers>
      <TaskUser RoleName="User"/>
    </TaskUsers>
  </Task>
  <Task type="final" id="Task_1sytah6">
    <TaskUsers>
      <TaskUser RoleName="Admin"/>
    </TaskUsers>
  </Task>
</Tasks>
```

I need to sql query for get `RoleName` in `Task` nodes that `type` of `Task` is `start`.
I test this query:

```
select m.c.value('@RoleName','varchar(max)') as RoleName
from Process as p
 outer apply 
  p.WorkflowXML.nodes('/Tasks/Task/TaskUsers/TaskUser') as  m(c)
where 
WorkflowXML.exist('/Tasks/Task[@type="start"]') = 1
```

but `WorkflowXML.exist` is not correct and return all of `RoleNames` in xml columns.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was much better to include your filter directly into the `XPath`:

```
select m.c.value('@RoleName','varchar(max)') as RoleName
from Process as p
outer apply p.WorkflowXML.nodes('/Tasks/Task[@type="start"]/TaskUsers/TaskUser') as  m(c)
```

Your approach with `WHERE` could get quite slow with bigger amounts/structures...

Comment: Simple and nice! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change `WHERE` statement to this:

```
WHERE m.c.value('../../@type','varchar(max)') = 'start'
```