# XQuery - get child node based on parent node

Tags: sql-server

I've been trying to figure out how to retrieve a child node based on a parent node using `SQL`. What I've tried so far is:

```
declare @streets xml
set @streets ='<ArrayOfStreetEntity>
     <StreetEntity>
     <Name>Street Name 1</Name>
     <PostalNumbers>
       <PostalNo>
        <FromNo>0</FromNo>
        <PostalCode>011369</PostalCode>
        <ToNo>0</ToNo>
       </PostalNo>
     </PostalNumbers>
     <StreetId>3</StreetId>
     </StreetEntity>     
     <StreetEntity>
     <Name>Street Name 2</Name>
     <PostalNumbers>
      <PostalNo>
        <FromNo>0</FromNo>
        <PostalCode>01136229</PostalCode>
        <ToNo>0</ToNo>
      </PostalNo>
      <PostalNo>
        <FromNo>4</FromNo>
        <PostalCode>01136255</PostalCode>
        <ToNo>5</ToNo>
      </PostalNo>
     </PostalNumbers>
     <StreetId>3</StreetId>
    </StreetEntity>
  </ArrayOfStreetEntity>'
```

In order to get the street names, I've used the below query which works fine:

```
SELECT
x.value(N'(Name)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') AS Name,
x.value(N'(StreetId)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') AS StreetId 

FROM @streets.nodes(N'/ArrayOfStreetEntity/StreetEntity') AS XTbl(x)
```

However, how would I get the first postal code based on the street name? I don't understand what I'm missing here.

What I've tried is the below code but it returns all postal codes:

```
select
xx.value(N'(PostalCode)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') AS PostalCode

from @streets.nodes(N'/ArrayOfStreetEntity/StreetEntity/PostalNumbers/PostalNo') AS XTbl(xx)
where xx.value(N'(/ArrayOfStreetEntity/StreetEntity/Name)[1]', 'varchar(max)')='Street name 1'
```

**Output:**

```
PostalCode
---------
011369
01136229
01136255
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38453156/get-attribute-value-of-xml-child-node-with-where-condition-on-parent-node) as a reference, try the below query:

```
select
xx.value(N'(PostalCode)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') AS PostalCode

from @strazi.nodes(N'/ArrayOfStreetEntity/StreetEntity/PostalNumbers/PostalNo') AS XTbl(xx)
where xx.value('../../Name[1]', 'varchar(max)')='Street name 1'
```

The above will return as many of child nodes where your street name matches your condition.

Answer (score 1):

Specify `StreetEntity` in the nodes path and change the value path to the first postal code:

```
SELECT
    xx.value(N'(PostalNumbers/PostalNo/PostalCode)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') AS PostalCode
FROM @streets.nodes(N'/ArrayOfStreetEntity/StreetEntity') AS XTbl(xx)
WHERE xx.value(N'(Name)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = 'Street name 1';
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
SELECT xx.value(N'(PostalNumbers/PostalNo/PostalCode)[1]', N'nvarchar(50)') AS PostalCode
FROM @streets.nodes(N'/ArrayOfStreetEntity/StreetEntity') AS XTbl(xx)
WHERE xx.value(N'Name[1]', N'varchar(50)') = 'Street name 1';
```